# using upyter notebook in vscode want to see all entries of pandas data tabled insted of "downsampled" data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I was wondering how would I be able to see the whole data set of the stock data that I requested?  I have about 2900+ entries but I am only able to see 1638.  Just wondering how would I be able to make vsCode increase this [image]

Don't know what to personally do to increase the size

Comment: I have posted the answer, but just out of interest, are you sure that your data has shape = 2000 ?  in the answer i post, you can see the shape in the `size` column.

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VScode shows the jupyter variables at the bottom.

So using this sample dataframe for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'a':np.ones(10000), 'b':np.zeros(10000)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df
```

You can then look at the variables at the bottom:
[image]

and click the small yellow box.

This will open a new tab, with **all of the data**.

[image]

with a scroll bar on the right hand side (in the default setup).

Comment: gotcha.  that actually works out better.  thank you very much.

Comment: it was a massive discovery when i found it. let's you explore the data properly without having to export it to a CSV file...  good question.

Comment: do you know of anyways/have you been able to apply the pandas conditional formatting to it?  just out of curioisty.

Comment: yes,  you can do this:  `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)` or this `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`, but it is not as good for "big" data... there is also `with pd.option_context()`...